# dynamic link change color after click only the first link colors change

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I create a dynamic link which created on the runtime and when I click on the link it change the color. But when I click on any other link it also change the first link not that link which I clicked.

My Code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
           {
                  <div class="contact-save">
                          
                           
                          
                   <a href="#" class="phone_number" id="favorite"onclick="Fav(@item.id)" >
                                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                 </div>
}
 <script>
      
        var btnvar = document.getElementById('favorite')
       function Fav(id) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("ajaxRent", "Home")';
        if(btnvar.style.color == "red"){
            btnvar.style.color = "grey"
        }
        else{
            btnvar.style.color = "red"
        }
        debugger

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.length == 0) // No errors
                    alert("Fave success!");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) { // Http Status is not 200
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) { // Whether success or error it enters here
            }
        }); 
    };

    
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with the below code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
           {
                  <div class="contact-save">
                          
                           
                          
                   <a href="#" class="phone_number" id="favorite"onclick="Fav(this)" >
                                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                 </div>
}
 <script>
      
        function Fav(x) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("ajaxRent", "Home")';
        if(x.firstElementChild.style.color == "red"){
            x.firstElementChild.style.color = "grey"
        }
        else{
            x.firstElementChild.style.color = "red"
        }
        debugger

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: x.id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.length == 0) // No errors
                    alert("Fave success!");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) { // Http Status is not 200
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) { // Whether success or error it enters here
            }
        }); 
    };

    
       </script>
```

**Important note:**
If phone number anchor tag is repeating then use unique ID every time.

Please let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: its working but my id value not pass to the controller it remain 0

Comment: Take the variable and save x.id in that variable and use it then in the ajax data id.

Comment: You can pass your @item.id in custom attribute like data-id="@item.id"

Comment: Then you this line to get that item id in the Fav function: x.dataset.id

Comment: You can pass it where ever you want

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: its take the value of anchor tag id not the  value of id of model which comes with @item.id

Comment: Okay, try to do the alert: alert(x.id). What you get?

Comment: sorry its work thankyou i want also to remain changed color after reloading or restarting page have you any idea

Comment: Now you need to get the value from the database and then match the ip address with the current user ip address and if it get matched with the database table data then make it fixed color

Comment: This is the solution and if it helped you. please upvote the answer. So it can beneficiary to others as well

Comment: if any example for this solution kindly tell me thankyou